# Android wear OS launch a web page on iPhone

Tags: android, ios, safari, wear-os, watch

In our watch app, we are implementing login flow via [DAG](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/auth-wear#DAG).
It works as expected with a connected iPhone, however, we are facing a problem with launching a verification URL on an iPhone.
`RemoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity()` does nothing and I'm looking for a proper trigger to launch Safari on my iPhone.

I have spoken with iOS colleagues about this topic and they suggested modifying an action from `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` to `openSafari` 
Moreover, I added a prefix for the URL, like this `safari-https://` without any success.

Is there a proper way to do that?

Comment: It has to be `ACTION_VIEW`, it is in the [contract](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:wear/wear-remote-interactions/src/main/java/androidx/wear/remote/interactions/RemoteActivityHelper.kt;l=259-262?q=RemoteActivityHelper). Also per contract, you have to add category `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE`. You can see a sample [here](https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/69ccda6f7228e0ff32d0765f13b3868b4d514dba/datalayer/watch/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/datalayer/watch/WearDataLayerAppHelper.kt#L72-L75).

Comment: More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps#get-phone-type). If it is still not working after checking these, I'd recommend raising an issue in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).